# Determining LED safety compliance

Tags: led, power, safety, laser, optics

I have a compliance audit that has been foisted on me from on high - as part of what an external consultancy has highlighted, I now have to prove that the indicator LEDs on a board I designed a long time ago are Class 1 laser compliant. Please do not point out how ridiculous this is.

I have the following specs for the LEDs in question:

- peak wavelength (595 nm)
- dominant wavelength (590 nm)
- spectral bandwidth (15 nm)
- luminous intensity (120 mcd)
- viewing angle (defined as the angle across which luminous intensity is 50% or more of maximum - 140º)

[Link to datasheet](http://katalog.we-online.de/led/datasheet/150060YS75000.pdf).

The [Wikipedia article on laser safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_safety) has [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_safety#/media/File:Laser_class_EN_60825-1.en.png) of maximum allowed CW power at various wavelengths and for various classes. It states that it is only valid for weakly divergent or collimated laser beams, but since Class 1 devices must be safe to view using any optical equipment, I can make the assumption that they are valid for the case where there exists a lens that can concentrate all of the available optical power from the LED onto the retina.

My big issue is that I can't seem to work out how to go from luminous intensity to optical power. I can convert from luminous intensity to luminous flux - however not to radiant flux (which I believe is equivalent to total optical power).

Can anyone shove me in the right direction?

Comment: An LED is not a laser -- it's as simple as that. You can concentrate the light from any noncoherent source (even an incandescent bulb) into the eye, but that doesn't make it a laser safety compliance issue. If you play along with their game, you're just encouraging the silliness.

Comment: Thanks Dave, and I agree. However I believe that high power LEDs do come under the legislation and by extension the burden is on me to prove that my LEDs are not high power.

Comment: You need to find the specific regulations that they're citing and read them for yourself.

Comment: In previous 10 years, I sold about 1 million 5 mm LEDs 10,000 mcd ~ 30,000 mcd 20~30 deg  which I expect it is would exceed Class 1 and were used for road, side walk tunnel emergency lights but hardly 120 mcd @ 140 deg. that's a joke right ?

Comment: Hi @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 - not a joke. Added the link to the datasheet. I totally agree that there's no tangible risk here - however, I need to provide calculated evidence or proof that I'm exempt from the requirement. Not trying to troll, trying to get people off my back!

Comment: Do yo understand the definitions yet for Candella and Lumens related to milliwatts?  Read those then come back with your specs ! as the laser specs are not relevant

Comment: Candela is power per unit is luminous power per solid angle, right, whereas lumens is total visible light emitted (luminous flux) right? Hence getting to luminous flux is a step in the right direction, but I need to get myself to something in units I can actually compare to limits in EN60825-1.

Comment: these are not relevant laser products, N.A.  anyone who says different is out of touch with reality

Comment: Light emitting diodes (LEDs) have been deleted from the scope of this document except for communication applications. LEDs are covered by IEC 62471

Comment: When did LEDs get deleted? I have a copy of IEC 60825-1 Edition 2.1 (inc. +A1:1997+A2:2001(E)) which specifically includes LEDs in the 1.1 scope section. Am I out of date?

Comment: ancient history (10yrs ago) , get the right specs and it will tell you

Comment: and it you need anything a bit brighter in IEC 62471   class 1  like >10Cd 30 deg let me know

Comment: Thanks @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 - you're quite right about the redaction. Time to have a quiet word with the auditors I think! Would you mind writing this up into an answer for the benefit of others? Alternatively I can, but I would prefer the answer to be properly credited to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Light emitting diodes (LEDs) have been deleted from the scope of this document IEC 60825-1 in 2007, except for communication applications ( very high intensity light focused beams).

LEDs are covered by IEC 62471 for Class 1, 2, 3.

I suggest you ask for the correct requirements. ( ie. spec)

Comment: Just found a caveat to this. The original auditors came back and had mistakenly identified our product as a toy. Apparently, with toys the old IEC 60825-1 is still applied (ridiculously). From EN 62115:

"EN 60825-1:1993 and its amendments are superseded by EN 60825-1:2007, which is based on IEC 60825-1:2007 and by
EN 62471:2008, which is based on IEC 62471:2006. However, for LEDs in toys a product standard based on ICNIRP Recommendations is in preparation and therefore EN 60825-1:1993 and its amendments will have to be used until this standard for LEDs in toys is implemented."

Comment: Is it a toy or a mistake?  If so, and, it is exempt from

Comment: In my case I am fine - it is their mistake. Just wanted to add the note for future visitors.

Comment: If it were so, it will be Class 1 (safe)  and, it is exempt from hazard symbol label.  5mm LEDs are only rated for 20mA , and since it is Yellow (590nmD) it will be 2.1V nom and thus only 42mW of heat and light and luminous power with 120 mcd @140deg since similar 140 deg Yellow LEDs are capable of >1,000 Cd in 5mm  , if we incorrectly assumed the efficacy was 100%, which is far reality , it could not possibly exceed 5mW of optical power and is more likely <0.5mW